# Failed to upload file using multipart/form data

Tags: android, multipartform-data

I'm facing problem to upload a file using multipart form data. I have given the screenshot of ARC with the api and my present code. Anyone's help will be appreciated.

[image]

```
public class MultiPortRequest<T> extends Request<T> {

    private static final String FILE_PART_NAME = "file";

    private MultipartEntityBuilder mBuilder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
    private final Response.Listener<String> mListener;
    private final File mImageFile;
    protected Map<String, String> headers;

    public MultiPortRequest(String url,Response.Listener<String> listener,
                                 ErrorListener errorListener,

                                 File imageFile)
    {
        super(Method.POST, url, errorListener);

        mListener = listener;
        mImageFile = imageFile;

        buildMultipartEntity();
    }

   @Override
    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
        Map<String, String> headers = super.getHeaders();

        if (headers == null
                || headers.equals(Collections.emptyMap())) {
            headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
        }

        headers.put("Identity", "rHTYsg8vZ/KWTaGOsy0eMNhngJMiZiK60pd9jAUQ+fI=");

        return headers;
    }

    private void buildMultipartEntity()
    {
        mBuilder.addBinaryBody(FILE_PART_NAME, mImageFile, ContentType.create("multipart/form-data"),
                mImageFile.getName());

        mBuilder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
        mBuilder.setLaxMode().setBoundary("xx").setCharset(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
    }

    @Override
    public String getBodyContentType()
    {
        String contentTypeHeader = mBuilder.build().getContentType().getValue();
        return contentTypeHeader;
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError
    {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        try
        {
            mBuilder.build().writeTo(bos);
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            VolleyLog.e("IOException writing to ByteArrayOutputStream bos, building the multipart request.");
        }

        return bos.toByteArray();
    }

    @Override
    protected Response<T> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response)
    {
        try {
            String result = null;
            result = new String( response.data, HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset( response.headers ) );
            return ( Response<T> ) Response.success( new JSONObject( result ), HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response) );
        } catch ( UnsupportedEncodingException e ) {
            return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
        } catch (JSONException je) {
            return Response.error(new ParseError(je));
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void deliverResponse(T response)
    {
        mListener.onResponse( response.toString());
        Log.v("yes", String.valueOf(mListener));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this will solve your problem

```
  public String sendFileToServer(String filelocation, String targetUrl) {
        String response = "error";
        Log.e("Image filename", filelocation);
        Log.e("url", targetUrl);
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        DataOutputStream outputStream = null;
        // DataInputStream inputStream = null;

        String pathToOurFile = filelocation;
        String urlServer = targetUrl;
        String lineEnd = "\r\n";
        String twoHyphens = "--";
        String boundary = "*****";
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy_MM_dd_HH:mm:ss");

        int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
        byte[] buffer;
        int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024;
        try {
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(
                    pathToOurFile));

            URL url = new URL(urlServer);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            // Allow Inputs & Outputs
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setUseCaches(false);
            connection.setChunkedStreamingMode(1024);
            // Enable POST method
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

            connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                    "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);

            outputStream = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
            outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);

            String connstr = null;

            String exension_withname=filelocation.substring(filelocation.lastIndexOf("/")+1);

            Log.v("esty",exension_withname);

            connstr = "Content-Disposition: form-data;filename=\"" + exension_withname + "\"" + lineEnd;
            Log.i("Connstr", connstr);

            outputStream.writeBytes(connstr);
            outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

            // Read file
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            Log.e("Image length", bytesAvailable + "");
            try {
                while (bytesRead > 0) {
                    try {
                        outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                    } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        response = "outofmemoryerror";
                        return response;
                    }
                    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                    bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                response = "error";
                return response;
            }
            outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens
                    + lineEnd);

            // Responses from the server (code and message)
            int serverResponseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
            String serverResponseMessage = connection.getResponseMessage();
            Log.i("Server Response Code ", "" + serverResponseCode);
            Log.i("Server Response Message", serverResponseMessage);

            if (serverResponseCode == 200) {

                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(  connection.getInputStream()));
                String line;
                while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line);
                }
                Log.v("esty","output:"+sb.toString());
                response = "true";
            }

            String CDate = null;
            Date serverTime = new Date(connection.getDate());
            try {
                CDate = df.format(serverTime);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e("Date Exception", e.getMessage() + " Parse Exception");
            }
            Log.i("Server Response Time", CDate + "");

            filelocation = CDate
                    + filelocation.substring(filelocation.lastIndexOf("."),
                    filelocation.length());
            Log.i("File Name in Server : ", filelocation);

            fileInputStream.close();
            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();
            outputStream = null;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            // Exception handling
            response = "error";
            Log.v("esty","Send file Exception"+ ex.getMessage() + "");
        ;
        }
        return response;
    }
```